# HTML Resize content of iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive, sendgrid

I'm currently using the prebuildt email form of sendgrid as an iFrame.

Everything is working as expected. The only problem I have is that on mobile devices the content of the iFrame is too big to get shown on the screen as you can see on the image:

[image]

So I tried to resize the content with the **scale: 0.5**, but it just make the whole iFrame smaller.

My current CSS-Code is the following:

```
 .bg-modal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.modal-contents {
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.iframeClass{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and my HTML is this:

```
<div class="bg-modal">
<div class="modal-contents">
    <iframe scrolling="no" class="iframeClass" frameborder="0" src="https://..."></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

I don't want to show the scrollbars.

Does someone know a solution for this repsonsive problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your device is lower resolution than 600px so it will scroll sideways.

You could use `max-width` to sort it out.

**The solution**

```
.bg-modal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.modal-contents {
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 100%; /* This makes it so if the device is under 600px, it will resize to be the width of the screen and it will not overflow */
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.iframeClass{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

If you are still getting problems, try this:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set width and height to 600px of the model-content and also 100% height and width of the iframe.So irespective of screen size iframe always 600px*600px.
You can fix it by set width to max-width and add some padding and mergin according to your design.
Or you can user vw for width and vh for height in model-content .

```css
.modal-contents {
    height: 600px;
    max-width: 600px;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 4px;

}

.iframeClass{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```